# Capybara Ambiguity Failure select list

Tags: html, rspec, capybara

I am getting
Ambiguous match, found 2 elements matching css ".active-result" with text "jeeny"

```
<select style="display: none;" class="form-control input-sm" id="column" name="column"><option value="">Select</option><option value="UPPER(supervisor.name)">jeeny roat</option>
<option value="UPPER(suprem.code)">jenny</option>
<option value="UPPER(officer.code)">carl</option></select>
```

it is able to detect jeeny roat bu not jenny

```
 chosen_select('jeeny', from: 'column')
 chosen_select('jeeny roat', from: 'column')
```

Also not able to detect value select select list is hidden

chosen_select is a helper method

Chosen::Rspec::FeatureHelpers  using instance method

```
  def chosen_select(value, *args)
    opt = args.extract_options!
    input = chosen_input(opt)
    args.unshift(value).uniq.each { |item| chosen_select!(input, item) }
  end
```

Comment: `chosen_select` is not a Capybara provided method, so what exactly is that doing?  Additionally what version of Capybara are you using?  You should probably also provide the actual html that is visible on the page for this widget, rather than the hidden select which Capybara won't interact with.

Comment: 'capybara', '2.1.0'

Comment: The visible div only displays selected items

Comment: Do you really mean 2.1.0 ?? If so update - that's ancient.  You are using a JS Widget -- judging by the name of your method probably the JQuery Chosen plugin - but without seeing the actual HTML that ends up visible on the page it's impossible to know (the HTML may be split in multiple places on the page - use inspect element while interacting with the page to figure out what is where).  Also, add the definition of `chosen_select` to your question because it's not provided by Capybara and may make it clearer exactly what is going on.

Comment: I can not update it at this moment is their any other way out

Comment: `chosen_select` is a helper method provided by what?  It's not from Capybara.  Find the code you're using and add it to the question (search in your app for `def chosen_select`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some searching, and am going to guess that you're using the `chosen-rails` gem which provides the `chosen_select` method defined at https://github.com/tsechingho/chosen-rails/blob/fb28dfcf0dca5ef49344a8d961b733b5bd96449f/lib/chosen-rails/rspec.rb  This ends up calling `chosen_select!` which should work due to the specifying of :prefer_exact for the matching method at https://github.com/tsechingho/chosen-rails/blob/fb28dfcf0dca5ef49344a8d961b733b5bd96449f/lib/chosen-rails/rspec.rb#L66 .  Since it's not working for you and the fact that you're still on Capybara 2.1.0 I'll guess you're also on a really old version of chosen-rails from before the matching method was specified.  If  that is the case, and you can't upgrade the gem, you can try specifying a Regexp to force the text find into exact mode

```
chosen_select(/\Ajeeny\z/, from: 'column'
```

Comment: Thanks a ton this works, I was confused to use regular exp in chosen select

Comment: @jerrytom glad it works, don't forget to accept the answer ISO the question gets marked as answered